# Multilevel pointers, stack or heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

Lets say I have this.

```
int ***a = new int**;
*a = new int*;
**a = new int;
***a = 18
```

So we have something like this. `[*] -> [*] -> [*]->[18]`

Are all of these pointers in the stack and everything they are pointing to in the heap?

Comment: Pointer variable `a` is on the stack, the memory they are pointing to is on the heap, as you allocated with `new`

Comment: I would think that just the very first pointer is on the stack. The second and third are allocated with `new` and will be on the heap.

Comment: Not true. All pointers but the first one are in the heap.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What stack? You're running under emscripten, don't forget that (yeah, you aren't, but given that emscripten works, the use of the word stack is misleading and useless).

Comment: I suggest thinking about "statically allocated" vs. "dynamically allocated" rather than "stack" vs. "heap"

Comment: [Please don't be a 3 star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: @JBL, statically allocated is not correct either. If you want to use C++-correct terms, say 'automatic storage'

Comment: @JBL Yes that's better terminology.

Comment: @SergeyA You're right, I just missed the edit window :(

Comment: -1 because this question cannot be answered without you clarifying what you're after. Stack is a platform-specific concept. The semantics of the C++ language itself don't necessitate that `a` is stored on a stack of any kind whatsoever. Please clarify whether: A. You want to understand the platform-independent semantics (meaning) of your code, or B. You have a question regarding the output the compiler produces for a particular platform - then you must include such output.

Comment: @KubaOber In the absence of the [tag:language-lawyer] tag, it's usually more helpful to assume a prototypical platform spec rather than consider all possible platforms, especially for learning-level questions like this one.  Even the [learncpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/) tutorial assumes this platform detail for educational purposes.

Comment: @MooseBoys Talking of storage durations explicitly makes things easier to understand, not harder to understand - what we care about is how long will the storage last, and who is in control of that. The concept of a stack is not necessary or particularly helpful to explain it. All that the asker cares for really is what's the storage duration of each pointer, and of the int value as stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming your code is inline in a function

```
int ***a = new int**;
```

a is on the stack. It points to something (thing1) on the heap

```
*a = new int*;
```

a is on the stack. It points to thing1.
thing1 now points to something else on the heap (thing2)

```
**a = new int;
```

a is on the stack. It points thing1.
thing1 on the heap points to thing2 on the heap.
thing2 points to an int on the heap

```
***a = 18
```

a is on the stack. It points thing1.
thing1 on the heap points to thing2 on the heap.
thing2 points to an int on the heap.
that int now = 18.

Comment: "a is on the stack" It is not. Show me where in the standard does it say it's on a stack. And for any implementation that you show that would store it on the stack, I'd show you one that doesn't. So please, let's get rid of this silly notion that there is some stack. The existence of such is completely tangential to the issue discussed in the question.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. @KubaOber, while technically correct, is being pedantic.  Any platform you're likely to be learning C++ on or likely to target in the near future will use a stack/heap paradigm for implementing the language.

Comment: @KubaOber - in the context of his question: a is on the stack. If you object to this answer you must also object to the question - he asks 'is a on the stack?'. I agree that it may well be in a register, on a punched card under his desk, anywhere the implementor of the compiler may choose. You need to distinguish between 'stack' as a conceptual type of variable vs 'stack' as a CPU construct. Also you know exactly what he is asking and what I am saying in reply

Comment: @pm100 There is no conceptual 'stack' type of a variable in the C++ standard. `a` is of autoamtic storage duration. That's all you can say about it. Such storage duration has certain semantics. That's it. I'm merely pointing out that unless the question had posted the assembly output, there's no way to tell whether `a` is on the stack. So you can't say it is. How do you know? You don't. Neither do I. Had we seen the assembly, we could tell.

Comment: please answer the question then indicating that there is not such thing as a stack variable. Ah - I see you already did, enjoy the feedback

Answer (score 0):

The very first pointer is on stack. The rest of them is on heap, since they were allocated using new.

Answer (score 0):

`a`  is on the stack. The rest, created by `new` is on the heap

Comment: Nah. It's a javascript variable. Nope. It's a register. Nope. Stack. It's an implementation detail that doesn't even have to exist.

Comment: Who's talking about java-script in this question?? Bringing this up, doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Since the question asks about C++ semantics in general, as long as you have a conformant platform, you're good. Emscripten is a conformant platform. The data lives in a nice, cozy javascript object. So, as you see, the whole talk of stack is completely unrelated to what the code *means* - and that was the question!

Comment: @KubaOber Well, _automatic storage_ would be a better term. Why answers used the term _stack_ is probably because the OP was using it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's on us, who know better, to tell the OP why the use of such term is unhelpful/misguided. Because, well, it is. The times where any expectation of automatics being on a stack of some sort was a sure bet is way past us, and none of it was mandated by standard C or C++ ever anyway IIRC.

Answer (score -3):

To understand what the code does, the concept of the stack is unnecessary. Some implementation that you use might put `a` on the stack, but that doesn't change the meaning of the code, and this detail is not necessary to understand what the code does.

If you don't believe me: in the C++ standard, the word stack only refers to `std::stack` and to the abstract *stack unwinding* concept.

To be specific, we must assume how your code is used. Let's assume that it is in a block of its own:

```
{
  int ***a = new int**; 
  *a = new int*;        
  **a = new int;
  ***a = 18;
}
```

What we are concerned with then is what is the storage duration of various pieces of storage.

1. The `a` has automatic storage duration. The storage exists until the closing brace.
2. `a` points to storage of type `int**` of dynamic storage duration. The storage lasts until you explicitly deallocate it - in this case, it outlives `a`.
3. `*a` points to storage of type `int*` of dynamic storage duration. Here too, the storage lasts until you explicitly deallocate it - in this case, it outlives `a`.
4. `**a` points to storage of type `int` of dynamic storage duration. Here too, the storage lasts until you explicitly deallocate it - in this case, it outlives `a`.
5. `***a` is the value `int(18)` stored in a piece of dynamic storage that `**a` points to.

What the program does, and how it behaves, has to do with these storage durations. It has nothing to do with whether `a` is on some stack. For all you know, you've compiled this code using  [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten), and the value lives in a javascript variable.

What is important that the storage duration of `a` is automatic, and its extent is to the end of the block in this case. The storage duration of everything you allocated with `new` is dynamic, and fully under your control.

With the code shown, there's no long-term way to access the three pieces of storage with dynamic storage duration: they will outlive `a`'s storage duration *and* turn into memory leaks as soon as the block ends. If you pass `a` out of the block, you'll be able to prevent this and retain the way of accessing all three dynamic storage duration pieces of storage.

Comment: Wrong. What tells you that a is a local variable?

Comment: @SergeyA We have to assume something :)

Comment: @KubaOber Let's also assume he's running on a typical C++ platform then and that the stack/heap paradigm applies.

Comment: @MooseBoys Given that LLVM/emscripten is very popular, you can have `a` on the stack, in a javascript variable, in a register, ... The issue is: the notion of stack completely muddies the water. It's unnecessary to call it out. Completely so. I bring up emscripten to show that you have normal C++ semantics on a platform without anything you'd normally have on a bare-metal CPU. Since we speak of semantics, the details such as that are unnecessary.

Comment: emscripten is irrelevant.

Comment: If you're going to be pedantic, then C/C++ has no concept of "heap" either, but you still used that term. In any case, any C implementation would need some form of storage for automatic variables which is naturally arranged as a stack data structure. That storage is what we call the "stack".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is very relevant, I've used it for a specific purpose. The question has to do with C++ semantics, and those stand on their own without any particular implementation. The question was not about what the implementation does, but about what the code means. The word "stack" is useless when discussing the semantics.

Comment: @interjay For the last decade I've been using a C implementation where the compiler uses statically allocated frames, so no, there is nothing "natural" about there being a stack. I mean I literally have tens of thousands of lines of code where stack is for return addresses and nothing else, and it's all just boring standard C. Stack is a term unnecessary when talking about what the code does. Feel free to edit my use of the word "heap" with whatever the correct standardese would demand instead.

Comment: If you look at the exceptions part of the standard it recognizes a "stack".  see 15.2.1

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "statically allocated frames". You must have some form of stack, or recursion would be impossible.

Comment: @interjay If I don't write recursive code, such stack is not materialized in the machine code. Again - stack is an implementation detail.

Comment: @NathanOliver The term *stack unwinding* as used in the standard is **an abstract term**, not married to there actually existing a physical stack structure in some memory. It has nothing to do with how the automatic storage might be implemented. In fact, apart from the talk about `std::stack`, the standard only uses the complete phrase *stack unwinding* - a whopping six (6) times at that. The word *stack* in isolation simply doesn't appear! Just look in the index.

Comment: @interjay In the particular case of the code in question, on the platform I'm using, `a` is not stored on the stack. Ever. In spite of the code still acting exactly as it should. So why use a term that has no relevance to the semantics of the code? *One* counterexample is enough to show how pointless the use of the term is in this case.

Comment: An optimization can change the behavior of the program in any way as long as the result is the same. I can say that `x++` increments the value of `x`, even if a certain implementation will optimize that out when it sees that it isn't needed. "Stack" is simply a term that people commonly use for automatic storage, and it's helpful because typically the storage is actually a stack (even if some optimizations may change this).

Comment: @interjay You're right, but the example you introduce is of a different sort. To understand C++ semantics in this respect you only care about storage durations, not where actually things end up. This makes it easier to understand, since the particular memory area where something is stored doesn't have any effect on the semantics of the code. E.g. if the code in question was in a block of its own, the dynamic storage duration data would outlive the automatic storage duration `a` and you'd get a (perhaps intentional) memory leak. That `a` is on a stack, in a register, etc. helps none IMHO.